# How can I run jQuery when text input value changes?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

All I want is to display a success message when a user changes the input value.  If it starts off as `foo` and a user types `s` making `foos`, I want to display a success message.

What am I missing?

Simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DdyNN/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" value="foo">
<div id="bar"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$('#foo').change(function() { 
    $('#bar').html('yay!');
});​
```

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/DdyNN/2/ If you need "live"-changes - use keyup event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the change event triggers when you leave the textfield. I would register to the keyup or keydown event.

Links:

- http://api.jquery.com/keyup/
- http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('#foo').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val()=='foos'){
        $('#bar').html('yay!');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

$.change() is for selects and not for input types. Try:

```
var currentvalue = $('#foo').val();
$('#foo').focusout(function(){
if($(this).val() != currentvalue){
$('#bar').html('yay!'); currentvalue = $(this).val();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DdyNN/6/)**

```
prv = $('#foo').val();
$('#foo').keyup(function() {
    if(prv + "s" == $(this).val()) 
       $('#bar').html('yay! success');
    else
       $('#bar').html('yay! failure'); 

        prv = $('#foo').val();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

This work on key pressed on the textbox when is focus

```
$('#foo').focus(function() { 
   $('#foo').keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val()=='foos')$('#bar').html('yay!');
      });
});​
```